# Implementing mirrored coloured glass VFX like in Ant Man

Tags: unity, graphic-effects, 3d-modeling

This might seem like a strange question but I've been wanting to implement VFX in one of my games similar to what we see in the first Ant Man movie. Specifically only this:

[image: Gif of the effect]

[Link to the gif above](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/UglyAdorableArgentinehornedfrog-size_restricted.gif)

1. What do you call a VFX/Object like this? Is there a term for this?
2. I'm assuming this is a job for a 3D artist. If so what is the best approach to building this? We are of course looking for a lower level of detail than the movie.

Comment: The GIF is very dark and it's hard to make anything out, however it looks like it's just a bunch of random reflective objects mirrored on both axes

Answer (score 2):

1. This is a [Kaleidoscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleidoscope)-like effect.
2. Assuming you're implementing this in Unity or Unreal Engine, you would either use a particle effect or a postprocess effect.

A particle effect would be used if you want the effect to show up somewhere in your 3D (or 2D) game world. A postprocess effect would be used if you want to modify the already-rendered image into this effect, or if you want to display the effect by itself in screen-space for, say, a loading screen.